# Salesforce send Survey email in sandbox is blank/empty

Tags: email, survey

When I enable Surveys in a sandbox, and try to send a survey through an email, the send email composer is blank / empty. I'm stuck on the survey modal with the text "Send Email" / "Add recipients, customize content, and use merge fields in your email. You can work with the HTML and preview your email's content."

If I insert an email template, nothing happens. If I hit "Next," the progress bar shows an error, but no fields show up in the modal.

I tried following the steps [in this bug article](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SHUAQA4&title=survey-email-composer-throws-an-error-we-couldn-t-find-the-record-you-re-trying-to-access-when-trying-to-send-an-email-with-the-survey-link), but there is no "Send Email" permission in Salesforce, I'm not sure if that matters.

[image: screenshot with text described above]